# How to test microphone functions with Virtual Devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, microphone, device-emulation, avd-manager

I am writing an Android App which needs to use the devices microphone.

To test my app, I installed various virtual devices using the AVD Manager of Android Studio.

However, I realise that for none of the virtual devices that I installed, the microphone was working.

I am using Android Studio 3.6.2 on MacOS Version 10.15.4 (Catalina).

I'd like to deploy my code on any virtual device in Android Studio and record sound via my MacBookPro's microphone.

Can anybody please let me know how I can install such virtual device and link the emulated microphone to my MacBookPro's microphone?

Answer (score 0):

Every android emulator has the option of `MicroPhone` which can be found in the running emulator's setting. You can configure your emulator and setup the microphone there:
[image]

Comment: I used various settings in the screen above, but unfortunately, no sounds comes through the emulated microphone. For physical devices, my code works very well.

Does this maybe have something to do with the settings for my AudioRecord Object?

I am using:

`AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);´
But also for these settings I've tried various options. My App still can't hear sound from my MacBook Pros Microphone (which works for Skype, Teams, etc. as well).